# How to use function that belongs to module 1 inside module 2?

Tags: module, julia

I'm trying to use a function that is inside a file (module 1) in another file (module) 2. But it gives me an error "ERROR: UndefVarError: t1 not defined". I have tried to export the function in module 1 but it also doesn't work. I'm new to Julia and I do not know very well how to handle modules.
Here is the code that I'm having problems.

First File: t1.jl

```
module A
    function soma(a::Int64, b::Int64)
        return a + b
    end
end
```

Second File: t2.jl

```
module B
    include("t1.jl")
    using .t1

    function main()
        s = soma(2, 3)
        println(s)
    end

    main()

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing t2.jl to:

```
module B
    include("t1.jl")
    using .A

    function main()
        s = A.soma(2, 3)
        println(s)
    end

    main()

end
```

prints out 5 as expected.

`include` is basically as if you'd copy-pasted the code from the included file into the current file - so, once you've `include`d `t1.jl` into module B, the fact that the file is called `t1.jl` has no relevance. It's `module A` that's in the current scope, and `A` is the namespace that contains the `soma` function we need. Hence, `using .A` is what's needed to make `soma` available within `B`.